# Trouble Creating org.w3c.dom.Document from xml string in java

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to create an org.w3c.dom.Document object from an xml string. I have followed what many have suggested in other questions but the document ends up empty. What is wrong with the following code?

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(response.getResponseText())));
```

And the xml text in the string looks like the following (this comes from response.getResponseText())

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://www.blah.com/ns/2006/05/01/webservices/123/TokenManagement_1/CreateServiceToken_1_Reply</a:Action>
    <CacheResponse xsi:type="DoNotStoreCacheResponse" xmlns="http://www.blah.com/ns/2008/03/01/webservices/123/Cache_1" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <Date>2012-09-04T15:35:06.8116593Z</Date>
        <DoNotStore />
    </CacheResponse>
    <a:RelatesTo>ba04425d-d93e-4a70-a134-ab8e29d5345c}</a:RelatesTo>
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
    <CreateServiceToken_Response_1 xmlns="http://www.blah.com/ns/2006/05/01/webservices/123/TokenManagement_1" xmlns:global="http://www.blah.com/ns/2006/05/01/webservices/123/Common_1">
        <Expiration>2012-09-04T17:04:19.1834228Z</Expiration>
        <global:Token>3DEC2723A01047D1590544CBA5BA1E30326535E609DC1E6FAC5C659BC3B8A693BB054834A58B235037ED830CD05784DB176A62309AEB4B608C6F0B5B3F13ADE0EC56BE9F822ACFA3B549D4427D89BF030BFF48BA671DCAEB49940EFEBDEBFB71</global:Token>
    </CreateServiceToken_Response_1>
</s:Body>
```

Can anyone see what is wrong with my code? I ultimately just want to run a couple of xpath queries on the document...

Comment: why do you say the document is "empty".  also, what is `response`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to start with setting `docFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);`, otherwise the parsing, the DOM built and the XPath implementation will not be able to work with XML with namespaces as you have posted.

Comment: I got the document to work by just taking the response stream and converting it straight to a document from the stream rather than converting it to string then to document. However, I upvoted and marked as answer because of the valuable piece of advice on setNameSpaceAware